# Why doesn't Doom 3 work in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, games, opengl

I've ran Doom 3 in several previous versions of Ubuntu, but I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, and get an error when trying to launch the game.

I have the latest proprietary ATI drivers installed, as well as the required 'ia32-libs' package for 32bit support. I get the following error:

```
DOOM 1.3.1.1304 linux-x86 Jan 16 2007 21:58:02
found interface lo - loopback
found interface eth0 - 192.168.1.2/255.255.255.0
------ Initializing File System ------
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/game00.pk4 with checksum 0xf07eb555
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/game01.pk4 with checksum 0x51c6981f
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/game02.pk4 with checksum 0xf3ec6f7
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/game03.pk4 with checksum 0x5d4230ea
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak000.pk4 with checksum 0x28d208f1
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak001.pk4 with checksum 0x40244be0
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak002.pk4 with checksum 0xc51ecdcd
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak003.pk4 with checksum 0xcd79d028
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak004.pk4 with checksum 0x765e4f8b
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak005.pk4 with checksum 0x8ffc3621
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak006.pk4 with checksum 0x95b65ab
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak007.pk4 with checksum 0x666bdb3c
Loaded pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak008.pk4 with checksum 0x23ae5993
Current search path:
/home/klusacek/.doom3/base
/usr/local/games/doom3/base
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak008.pk4 (3 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak007.pk4 (38 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak006.pk4 (48 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak005.pk4 (63 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak004.pk4 (5137 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak003.pk4 (4676 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak002.pk4 (6120 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak001.pk4 (8972 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/pak000.pk4 (2698 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/game03.pk4 (2 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/game02.pk4 (2 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/game01.pk4 (2 files)
/usr/local/games/doom3/base/game00.pk4 (2 files)
game DLL: 0x0 in pak: 0x0
Addon pk4s:
file system initialized.
--------------------------------------
----- Initializing Decls -----
------------------------------
------- Initializing renderSystem --------
using ARB renderSystem
renderSystem initialized.
--------------------------------------
5206 strings read from strings/english.lang
Couldn't open journal files
execing editor.cfg
execing default.cfg
couldn't exec DoomConfig.cfg
couldn't exec autoexec.cfg
5206 strings read from strings/english.lang
----- Initializing Sound System ------
sound system initialized.
--------------------------------------
----- R_InitOpenGL -----
Setup X display connection
dlopen(libGL.so.1)
dlopen(libGL.so.1)
idRenderSystem::Shutdown()
signal caught: Segmentation fault
si_code 1
Was in fatal error shutdown: Unable to initialize OpenGL
Trying to exit gracefully..
```

And the output of: glxinfo | grep direct:

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your OpenGl isn't working. What does this gives you: glxinfo | grep direct

Comment: Yeah I see that at the end. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Put the output of: glxinfo | grep direct

Comment: Here's the output: direct rendering: Yes
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_name_gen_delete, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,

Comment: Thanks. I tired that, but it didn't work. I get the same error. I just installed Warsow, which I believe uses Open GL, and it works fine.

Comment: Open a terminal and type the following: export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libGL.so.1   make sure that that file exists there, or point to the right location, then run Doom

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4502/discussion-between-lnxslck-and-devi710)

Answer (score 3):

I got it to run! The problem was my ATI video drivers and configuration. I removed and installed the newest (just came out today) ATI drivers following the excellent guide here:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29

In addition, my system is running faster than ever xD. Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Also uou need to be running a 24bpp desktop. If you use the glxinfo commands, you will see 24bpp modes in the visuals list:

$ glxinfo
[..]
   visual  x  bf lv rg d st colorbuffer ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav

### id dep cl sp sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat

0x21 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  0  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
[..]

So open a terminal type:

> glxinfo

And see if you're on a 24bpp desktop

If you're on a 24bpp desktop, try this:

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libGL.so.1

Point to the correct location of libGl.

Comment: humm... I think it is running 24bpp. I ran the glxinfo command and I have a visual list that is the same as you have posted above. Does that mean it is 24bpp? Is there a particular column or row that I should be looking at?

Comment: Second row, example above shows 24

Comment: Ahhh. I got you, under 'dep'. Yes it is 24: 0x023 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
Any other ideas? Thanks for all you help with this.

Comment: The LD_PRELOAD command didn't work. It's interesting that in /usr/lib/ I have three sym-link files named: libGL.so, libGL.so.1, libGL.so.1.2. The last one points to /usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2. I also tried the LD_PRELOAD command with that file path, but I still get the same error.